# MLE using multivariate normal distribution

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, statistics

I am reading econometrics lecture notes of a Japanese professor. To explain MLE estimation he uses multivariate normal distribution. [image: mle]

As you can see, the first line is the loglikelihood function and the second line is proportional to the first line equation. I cannot get my head around this. How and why the first equation can be written as the second one using trace of a matrix. I heard about "trace trick" and this must be the application of this trick, but I need help to understand it and possibly use it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "trick" you are referring to is a property of the trace of a product of matrices, namely

$${\rm tr}(ABC) = {\rm tr}(BCA)$$

assuming the dimensions are conformable of course.

Now, note that the dimension of $(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (x_n-\mu)$, for each observation, is $1 \times 1$. So trivially,

$${\rm tr}\Big[(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (x_n-\mu)\Big] = (x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (x_n-\mu) $$

But since also, from the mentioned property of the trace,

$${\rm tr}\Big[(x_n-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1} (x_n-\mu)\Big] = {\rm tr}\Big[\Sigma^{-1} (x_n-\mu)(x_n-\mu)^T\Big]$$

combining one gets the alternative expression for the mutlivariate normal log-likelihood.